# Coredata inferred mapping model is failing on my old databases

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using CoreData for one of my databases, and I'm having trouble with an upgrade to my App.

My old databases are no longer loading ... I get the error "Cocoa error 134190" which I believe means that the inferred mapping model is failing.

When I started editing this version of my App, I created a new model version, and I simply added one new attribute to one entity, and two new attributes to another entity. Nothing was changed or deleted.

I've checked inside my App's directory, and all of the model versions are there.

I even have a snapshot of my previous version of the App, and with that snapshot I can load my core data files.

To debug what is going wrong, I took the exact data model from my previous snapshot and used it in my current version, and I still get the error.

I've even done a "diff" on every file in my ".app" directory packages, and there are only two files that are different between the two. One is the actual binary for the application, and the other is the "Info.plist" file. I looked at the Info.plist files, and they too are basically identical (the new one has a newer bundle version, but no other change).

Any idea why the inferred mapping is broken?

I am getting the same error even when the data models are completely unchanged from my last version which works.

This is extremely frustrating.

Any information as to how to track down problems like this in the future would also be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer ... the problem was that in my new version, I was rearranging the locations of my files. I did so by simply moving the database to a new location. What I didn't realize is that coredata databases have some knowledge of their path built in, and you can't simply move them.

I needed to change the location of the database using the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's method:

migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:

My fault, but I really wish that core data error messages weren't so cryptic.

In the next version of my App, I'm going to remove core data completely.

Ron

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe core data actually cares where the database file is, but I could be wrong. In the times I have seen this error, specifically "Cocoa error 134190" while trying to infer a model mapping, it's been the case that there was actually a problem trying to migrate to the next version of the model.

For example, when I found this thread today because I was helping someone with this problem, the real underlying issue was that the type of one of the attributes was accidentally changed. The automatic migration can't handle that sort of change.

A somewhat easy way to look at the changes between two model versions is to diff the description files themselves on the command line with diff:

```
diff yourNameHere.xcdatamodeld/yourNameHere5.xcdatamodel/contents yourNameHere.xcdatamodeld/yourNameHere4.xcdatamodel/contents
```

(That assumes you have a core data model description named "yourNameHere" and you're looking at a problem migrating from version 4 to 5. You'll have to adjust for your specific files.) In this diff you should see whatever additional things you've added, but you're really looking for something like a type changing when it shouldn't.